# StructureMap configuration for Constructor Enum Parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

Could anyone suggest the xml configuration for the below StuctureMap DI code. `BrowserType` is enumerator.

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    // Tell StructureMap to look for configuration 
    // from the App.config file
    // The default is false
    //x.PullConfigurationFromAppConfig = true;
    x.For<ITranslatorEngine>().Use<Translator>().Ctor<BrowserType>().Is(BrowserType.IE);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with StructureMap, so I'm going to guess, but I think you can do something like this:

```
<StructureMap MementoStyle="Attribute">
  <DefaultInstance
    PluginType="assembly-qualified name of ITranslatorEngine"
    PluggedType="assembly-qualified name of Translator"
    browserType = "IE" />
</StructureMap>
```

Assuming that "browserType" is the name of the constructor argument in the Translator class.

You can place the XML in the App.config file or StructureMap.config, and then modify the `ObjectFactory.Initialize` call to set the appropriate property for the config source.

More details are available on the StructureMap site:

- [Configuring StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ConfiguringStructureMap.htm)
- [Xml Configuration](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/XmlConfiguration.htm)

Edit: according to [this page](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/AttributeNormalized.htm#section4), string names of the enumeration should be used as values.

---

Here's a fully working sample based on StructureMap 2.6.1:

**Translator.cs:**

```
namespace StructureMapTests
{
    public interface ITranslator
    {
    }

    public enum BrowserType
    {
        IE,
        Firefox,
        Chrome
    }

    public class Translator : ITranslator
    {
        public Translator(BrowserType browserType)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
namespace StructureMapTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => 
                           { 
                              x.PullConfigurationFromAppConfig = true; 
                           });

                var translator = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ITranslator>();

                Console.WriteLine(translator == null);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="StructureMap" type="StructureMap.Configuration.StructureMapConfigurationSection,StructureMap"/>
  </configSections>

  <StructureMap MementoStyle="Attribute">
    <DefaultInstance PluginType="StructureMapTests.ITranslator, StructureMapTests" 
                     PluggedType="StructureMapTests.Translator, StructureMapTests"
                     browserType="IE">

    </DefaultInstance>
  </StructureMap>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, 'browserType' is an Translator constructor argument. Because it is an enum we can not attribute it as browserType="BrowserType.IE". When I do that it give me an exceptions "StructureMap Exception Code:  205
Missing requested Instance property "browserType" for InstanceKey "

Comment: @Praveen What error are you getting? I set up a fake console app project as a test. The relevant code is in my answer.